# how do i create the hyperlink in this text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, hyperlink

I create this code
i want to make the text become a hyperlink
when i try to test this
this code will go to the default page

```
$("body").data("q1", {
    id: "q1",
    title: "Is the interest attributable to a business carried on in Malaysia by the " +  '<a href :\"http://prod.resource.wkasiapacific.com/resource/scion/document/default/wmwttcomm1Uio1659397sl244904519?cfu=default\"> non-resident?</a>',
    next: "q2",
    back: "intro",
    yes: "c1",
    no: "q2",
    answer : ""
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The a-tag in the title string looks weirdly formatted, also i don't know there's any particular reason you would split the string into two.

Try setting the title like so

```
...
title: 'Is the interest attributable to a business carried on in Malaysia by the  <a href=\"http://prod.resource.wkasiapacific.com/resource/scion/document/default/wmwttcomm1Uio1659397sl244904519?cfu=default\"> non-resident?</a>'
...
```